# Will a sheet of carbon atoms reflect radio waves?

Tags: waves, reflection, scattering, radio-frequency, radar

I am working out some details in a SciFi novel. I'm thinking of having spec ops who would use a device that could manipulate carbon atoms to form and maintain large, rigid, one-atom thick carbon sheets as wings. They would then be able to glide for great distances, or even fly like birds.

### Situation

Let's say said spec ops members glide pass an area where an average military radar is active.

### What I have learned

1. Radars fire radio waves into a distance and listen for the reflection to "see" things.
2. Part of a radar's radio waves would pass through objects/structures that are thinner than the wavelength.
3. Part of a radar's Radio waves would also reflect off a surface.
4. Stealth planes work by deflecting the waves at awkward angles so that the radar would not receive strong reflections. Its paint is also designed to absorb some of the waves, but paint alone only has minor effect.

Please do correct me if I've got anything wrong here.

### Questions

Would a single-atom thick sheet of carbon reflect any waves at all?

Would the radar easily detect the soldiers because of the wings? (Well, for a humanoid to fly, a wingspan of 7 meters would be necessary. That's huge.)

Comment: I fear you have more reality-related problems than just identifying the spectral bands where reflectivity is high.  Sheets one atom thick cannot have rigidity.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Since he is writinga SciFi novel, there is already a solution to the material strength problem; a field generator that increases the strength of the molecular bonds. This is how the _General Products_ hulls work in the Larry Niven universe.

Comment: @OscarBravo Thanks for your input. Will take a look at the General Products hulls. Though I probably should ask the question on SciFi's stack. Just discovered its existence lol.

Comment: @OscarBravo  Sure,  but then his field generator can do whatever it wants to  reflectivity too.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments to the question that using one atom layer as wings might be problematic. However, I still want to make a few points in a direct answer to the question.

- Carbon can adopt multiple crystalline forms, of which the most well-known as diamond, graphite/graphene, fullerenes and carbon nanotubes. Since the question is about a "sheet of carbon atoms", I assume that we are talking about *graphene* (graphite is compose of multiple graphene sheets stacked together).
- Graphene is a semimetal, that is the conduction and the valence bands touch in a single point - there is really no gap (as in isolators/semiconductors), but the density-of-states at the Fermi level is zero (so it is not really a conductor). It is however easily converted to a metal by applying potential to a metallic gate, placed below the graphene sheet, and thus shifting the Fermi level (it is easily done in laboratory conditions). Thus, while graphene is not metallic, any fluctuations of surrounding potential can make it conducting (at least in some places).
- Even a single layer of a real metal would be mostly transparent for electromagnetic radiation (although some of it would be certainly scattered/reflected). Despite the metals' reputation for reflecting electromagnetic waves and expelling the electric field, the electric field does penetrate inside of a metal, decaying exponentially inside. This is called [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), and its characteristic length is certainly bigger than an atomic layer.

Comment: Since he is trying to avoid detection by radar, he specifically wants the material to be _non_-metallic. So I think the rest of your answer confirms that graphene would be a great choice for this task.

Comment: @OscarBravo Indeed, I deviated from the point of the question in my answer. I have corrected it.